# C# HTML Agility Pack - Using a variable in SelectNodes

Tags: c#, html-agility-pack

What is the syntax for using a variable in the SelectNodes parameters?

For example,

```
string foo = "bar";
```

This works

```
nodes = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@id='bar']");
```

But

```
nodes = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@id=foo]");
```

finds no nodes. The issue arises because I can't be sure what the id string will be, so I have to use the variable approach. What is the proper syntax?

The html looks like

```
<span id="bar">text</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

Use it Like this:

```
string foo = "bar";

nodes = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//span[@id='"+ foo + "']");
```

Answer (score 0):

The parameter accepted by SelectNodes is just a string. You could declare a string in advance or just do it all in one line.

```
string idName = "bar";
string xpath = "//span[@id='" + idName + "']";
nodes = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes(xpath);
```

Or another way to do the same thing with a different string formatter:

```
string idName = "bar";
nodes = hd.DocumentNode.SelectNodes($"//span[@id='{idName}']");
```